# How to make Text Centered in Textbox w/ Calendar Extender

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, calendar

How do you make the text in a textbox centered if the textbox contains a Calendar extender? I tried CSS and code inside of the ASP.NET to set the text to 'centered', however; I got an error with details about style="...centered" isn't an acceptable argument with a calendar extender.

**Code for Textbox and Calendar Extender**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtAnniversary" runat="server" style="margin-left: 11px"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:CalendarExtender ID="AnniversaryClndr" runat="server" Enabled="true" PopupPosition="Right" TargetControlID="txtAnniversary">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

---

This is where I set the text of the textbox containing the CalendarExtender. ep is the employee object, and Date is a DateTime variable in Employee.

Is there a way to make the text of a textbox containing a CalendarExtender **centered**?

```
this.txtAnniversary.Text = ep.Date.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: You wrote you had an error with `style="...centered"`. This was `style="text-align:center"`, right? Or did you just happen to make a mistake in writing?

Comment: I just didn't want to write out text-align in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<asp:scriptmanager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAnniversary" runat="server" 
        style="margin-left: 11px; text-align:center" 
        ontextchanged="txtAnniversary_TextChanged" Text = "Sanket"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtAnniversary_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtAnniversary">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>

</div>
</form>
```